# Removing view from UITableViewCell's accessoryView not working

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uitableview, accessoryview

I've set a uiview with image in my cell's accessoryView and later on I want to remove this view so that the accessoryType can be shown once again as none. The following doesnt work -

```
  //create cell
        UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        //initialize double tick image
        UIImageView *dtick = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dtick.png"]];
        [dtick setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
        UIView * cellView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)];
        [cellView addSubview:dtick];

 //set accessory type/view of cell
        if (newCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
            newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }
        else if(newCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){
                newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
                newCell.accessoryView = cellView;
            }
        else if (newCell.accessoryView == cellView) {
            newCell.accessoryView = nil;
            newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
          }
```

I've also tried [newCell.accessoryView reloadInputViews] but that doesn't work either.

Basically I want to cycle through these states upon click on cell => no tick -> one tick -> double tick (image) -> no tick

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

- In `newCell.accessoryView == cellView` you compare the cell's accessory view with a newly
  created image view: This comparison will never yield TRUE.
- When you set the accessory view to your image, you also set the type to `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone`, so that the next time it will be set to `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` again. In other words, the second `else if` block will never be executed.

The following code could work (but I did not try it myself):

```
if (newCell.accessoryView != nil) {
     // image --> none
     newCell.accessoryView = nil;
     newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
} else if (newCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
     // none --> checkmark
     newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else if (newCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
     // checkmark --> image (the type is ignore as soon as a accessory view is set)
     newCell.accessoryView = cellView;
}
```